# For a IOS Phonegap App, is it okay to include javascript files not local to the app

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, performance-testing

I'm using Phonegap, developing for IOS.  The documentation stated something about not being allowed to upload new Code to an app.  Does Apple allow us to do the following:

```
  <script src='http://www.myurlserver.com/dir/dir/myfiles.js'></script>
```

And is it okay to hotlink images from my server as well?

I just want to make sure my app doesn't get rejected.  This would allow me to push new javascript code like bug fixes and new content, without waiting 7 days for the apple review process.

Comment: Apple doesn't restrict loading external JS file.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed hotlink images from your server. Apple doesn't have issues with that. You can go ahead and do it!

Comment: could you please share some reference documents from Apple regarding the same.

Comment: Apple only rejects apps that use third party or non-public APIs. They nowhere say we cannot use private servers just to load contents. So, we should be good-to-go.

Comment: thanks for the information. What I'm looking for is that official document/statement from Apple where it is mentioned.